# The multi-part identifier could not be bound on Temp Table Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it's been asked many times before, however I seem to have run into an odd problem.

I'm trying to collect data to display in a graph about the sum of money owed per month per cargo.

I'm trying to join my query onto a temp table of months, so even if there is no data for that month, I will still get a value of 0 for the graph.

my code:

```
INSERT INTO #DemurrageValuesExport
        SELECT #Months.Month,
                        SUM(CASE
                            WHEN ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0) < 0
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0)
                        END) AS [Potential Demurrage]
        FROM        dbo.Trip
                    RIGHT JOIN dbo.TripCargo
                        ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripCargo.TripID 
                    RIGHT JOIN dbo.Cargo
                        ON dbo.TripCargo.CargoID = dbo.Cargo.ID
                    LEFT JOIN #Months
                        ON Month = PD.Berthed
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.PotentialDemurrageEvents AS PD
                        ON dbo.Trip.ID = PD.TripID
                        AND PD.Berthed BETWEEN @MonthStartDate AND @MonthEndDate
                        AND dbo.TripCargo.ID = PD.TripCargoID
        WHERE dbo.Cargo.ID = @CargoID AND TripCargo.Export = 1
        GROUP BY    Month
```

This loops through each of the previous 12 months, getting values for a particular cargo.

The problem arises on; `ON Month = PD.Berthed`

It is claiming that `PD.Berthed` could not be bound. However, I've used the alias in other places in the query and they are not causing issues. If I remove the temp table join, the query executes fine.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? Or failing that, achieve what I'm trying to do without joining onto another table of months at all?

Thanks

Comment: use `aliases` with table names. the sql parser is confused that at what point to which `Month` column you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliasing the temp table is definitely going to help clear things up, but we also have to change the order of `JOIN`s because at the point that you attempt to join to `#Months`, the `PD` alias hadn't yet been introduced:

```
INSERT INTO #DemurrageValuesExport
    SELECT m.Month,
                    SUM(CASE
                        WHEN ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0) < 0
                        THEN 0
                        ELSE ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0)
                    END) AS [Potential Demurrage]
    FROM        dbo.Trip
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.TripCargo
                    ON dbo.Trip.ID = dbo.TripCargo.TripID 
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.Cargo
                    ON dbo.TripCargo.CargoID = dbo.Cargo.ID
                LEFT JOIN dbo.PotentialDemurrageEvents AS PD
                    ON dbo.Trip.ID = PD.TripID
                    AND PD.Berthed BETWEEN @MonthStartDate AND @MonthEndDate
                    AND dbo.TripCargo.ID = PD.TripCargoID
                LEFT JOIN #Months m
                    ON m.Month = PD.Berthed
    WHERE dbo.Cargo.ID = @CargoID AND TripCargo.Export = 1
    GROUP BY    m.Month
```

Fully aliased-up version:

```
INSERT INTO #DemurrageValuesExport
    SELECT m.Month,
                    SUM(CASE
                        WHEN ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0) < 0
                        THEN 0
                        ELSE ISNULL(PD.PotentialDemurrageCost,0)
                    END) AS [Potential Demurrage]
    FROM        dbo.Trip t
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.TripCargo tc
                    ON t.ID = tc.TripID 
                RIGHT JOIN dbo.Cargo c
                    ON tc.CargoID = c.ID
                LEFT JOIN dbo.PotentialDemurrageEvents AS PD
                    ON t.ID = PD.TripID
                    AND PD.Berthed BETWEEN @MonthStartDate AND @MonthEndDate
                    AND tc.ID = PD.TripCargoID
                LEFT JOIN #Months m
                    ON m.Month = PD.Berthed
    WHERE c.ID = @CargoID AND tc.Export = 1
    GROUP BY    m.Month
```

Comment: +1 for the "Fully 'aliased-up' version" , it just made laugh when read it Fully 'aliased-up' version lol

Answer (score 1):

This is because you join the table after you try to refer to it. Move the join to #Months after it

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.PotentialDemurrageEvents AS PD
-- ...
LEFT JOIN #Months
       ON Month = PD.Berthed
```